# Green waste over the fence

Tags: property, trees

So I moved in to a house with a rather big yard that I'm not using very often, but it is mine. Right next to the fence I have a big tree that branches of it cross the fence to my neighbour's garden but just in a bit. The neighbour is now telling me I ought to pay them for removing the green waste every fall, $1000.
They say that because of the wind most leaves fall at their side.

Is it my problem or theirs?

Comment: What jurisdiction? (you do write $, so United States?)

Comment: "yard" also suggests "North America".  UK would say "garden".

Comment: I did live in oklahoma for a bit

Comment: @YviDe I assumed UK bc OP asked contemporaneous questions about UK

Comment: So, are you asking about Oklahoma? Please edit and tag the question appropriately. If you think it doesn't matter - in my home country, yes, you might have to pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theirs. Unless your tree is causing significant damage.

> ... if any leaves from your neighbour’s tree fall into your garden in
>   autumn, you have no right to ask them to come around and sweep them
>   up.

http://www.problemneighbours.co.uk/rights-trees-and-overhanging-branches.html